# Complicated Javascript string modify

Tags: javascript, string

I have this string here:

```
<br><br>|Me-Foo|: htht
```

What i want to do is to transform it to this:

```
<br><br>Me: htht
```

basically to change only the part inside the two "|", remembering tha the "Foo" might change with another name, like "john" or whatever.
.. But I don't know how to!? A quick solution anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can remove that with...

```
str = str.replace(/\|(\w+)-\w+\|/, '$1');
```

You didn't specify the constraints of what appears between the pipes. If word characters (`\w`) aren't flexible enough, adjust as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with combination of `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf`, and `substring` js methods... [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell the general case from your example, but let me try:

```
str = str.replace(/\|([^|]+)-Foo\|/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?

```
theString = theString.replace(/\|(.+)-.+\|/, "$1");
```

There are several answers given. This one replaces

```
"anything*& 45|anything8  \$-().?anything|  90fanything"
```

with

```
"anything*& 45anything8  \$  90fanything"
```

The best answer depends on what could possibly be in between the pipes.